# Please undelete this moderator-deleted question on SO

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, specific-question, undelete-request

[Clear file cache to repeat performance testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478340/clear-file-cache-to-repeat-performance-testing)

I found it to be incredibly useful in helping me resolve some performance testing issues when experimenting with DLL loading alternatives.  Pointed me to exactly the tool that I needed to avoid having my tests skewed by file system caching.  I could only see it because I have enough privileges.  I think it would be helpful to other programmers doing performance testing and should be available in the foremost forum for programmer questions.

Comment: Seems off-topic for SO, though.

Comment: It was closed as a duplicate of (flagged as asuch by a user) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405868/how-to-invalidate-the-file-system-cache

Comment: The question may be a duplicate, but the answer I found very useful wasn't on the other question.  In such cases the answers should either be merged or it should be closed, but not deleted.

Comment: @Oded flagged as such by the author of the proposed duplicate. The proposed duplicate was posted years after the question in the OP here.

Comment: But as deleted it'll be invisible to most people, and the answers are different. Perhaps migration is a better option.

Comment: Not arguing with you guys. Just s'plaining what seems to have happened.

Comment: @DaveNewton Migrations isn't possible for old questions.  It should just be re-asked on the appropriate site, if that site doesn't have a dup for it.

Comment: @Chris I don't subscribe to the narrow view that system-related questions are always off topic.  In this case the question is clearly related to performance testing and, as such, is very much on-topic for programmers.

Comment: Given that you have a blog and are able to see the content, why not host it on your blog? It doesn't seem to be a good fit for SO.

Comment: @Bart I wish my blog were as popular as SO for people looking for answers to their questions.  I suppose if I don't get any traction getting it opened up on what I consider the best place for it to be found that is an option, though.

Comment: I have to say that there is an asymmetry here. If they are duplicates than (1) surely the earlier question has precedence (especial as the newer one has fewer views and votes) and (2) they should be either both extant or both deleted. One of each can't be right. Further, deleting the earlier questions after the OP of the later one flagged it encourages bad behavior. *Aside: flagging an earlier question as a duplicate of your own latter one is simply crass.*

Comment: @dmckee The post with better questions and answers should be left open, and the post with lower quality content should be closed as the dup of the other, regardless of the time either was posted.  I agree it doesn't make sense for only one to be deleted though.

Comment: This "Migrations isn't possible for old questions" blanket answer keeps being used as a justification for deletion. Why is it not possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This post wasn't actually closed, although it does cover the same ground as the pointed duplicate.

It opens with this:

> What tools are available to either completely clear, or selectively remove cached information about file and directory contents?

While tools that programmers commonly use are on topic for Stack Overflow, this does delve a bit into the realm of *pin a tool on my problem*. It's anchored in a concrete problem that someone needed to solve, but as it's written, it invites a bit of a popularity contest when it comes to answers. I agree that the question should be closed, and I understand why the moderator responding to the flag deleted it, but clearly, there's content that might be worth salvaging here - perhaps through a merge.

To be clear, I'm not overriding the decision that the moderator took, it's clear to me that the action was taken because the question was quite old and *very unlikely* to gather votes in either direction from the community, and it is problematic. I don't think eyes on that question are a problem any longer - and I have restored the question, but in a closed state.

Have at it, if you think a merge is warranted - use your flags. If you think there's value in some answers that could be duplicated purely for the purposes of preservation - grab them, just be sure to give [proper attribution](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).